# vue-router передача параметров

Tags: apache2, vue.js

Разъясню вопрос. Имеется файл app.js вида:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
Vue.use(VueRouter);

import Users from './Components/Users.vue'

const routes = [
    { path: '/users/:id', component: Users },
    { path: '/:id', component: Users },
];
const router = new VueRouter({
    routes,
    mode: 'history'
});

Vue.component('index', require('./Components/Test.vue'));

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    router
});
```

в index.html вставлен тег `<index></index>` и подключен собранный webpack файл js. Если обратиться к сайту по пути `example.loc/1`, то нам прекрасно отобразится User component с переданным id. Если обратиться к сайту по пути `example.loc/users/1`, то белый лист и ошибка `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <`. Имеется в корне файл `.htaccess` вида:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

Так же конфиг (сервер lamp, php 7, ubuntu 16.04) имеет следующие настройки:

```
<Directory "/var/www/example/">
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

`a2enmod rewrite` так же сделан. Прошу помочь.

Edited: Ошибка следующая `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ответ до безобразия прост, надеюсь никто большо не столкнется с такой проблемой... Вся суть заключается в подключении компилируемого файла webpack в index.html, у меня подключение шло не из корня и поэтому была ошибка. Разъясню: вместо `<script src="/js/bundle.js"></script>` было `<script src="js/bundle.js"></script>` (нужен `/` в начале)

Comment: Да да)) абсолютный путь важен))